# I want to use parameterized query in @databricks/sql node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, parameters, sql-injection, databricks-sql

Query = `"select * from repos where id="sj"`

parameterized =

```
"select * from repos where id = ?"
result - executestatement(parameterized,"sj")
```

I want to pass parameters to the sql query for @databricks/sql module but I am unable to figure out a way. The node.js package has this issue listed if anybody knows a work around?

Parameterizing the query for prevention of sql injection of application.